# Windows / PyPi / PyCharm linker errors when compiling some cython modules

Tags: python, pycharm, pypi, mingw-w64

currently, i am working with PyCharm on Windows, and i tried to install some packages via PyPi. For convinience, i used the integrated functionality of PyCharm, which does essentially the same as the shell easy_install.

However, when installing packages which have to be compiled with gcc, i get some errors. I already browsed a lot of questions here on stackoverflow because of the former errors, and managed to overcome some of the errors (using mingw64, removing the -mno-cygwin parameter from the setup scripts etc) but now i'm totally stuck on this one:

build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\cpyamf\amf0.o:amf0.c:(.text+0xb912): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ImportError'

c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\cpyamf\amf0.o: bad reloc address 0x78 in section `.data'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

The error occurs on the installation of PyAMF and Twisted, which use cython for some parts. I couldn't find a solution for that one yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your installation command work from the terminal? In other words, is the issue related to the library being installed or to the package manager of PyCharm?

Comment: pip install pyamf yields the same errors as pycharm does :/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with help from the folks at #python on freenode. Or better: found a workaround.

The problem was basically that i used 64 bit python on windows, which doesn't really work well with minGW64 and stuff.

I installed 32 bit Python, edited the distutils.cfg fixed the -mno-cygwin problem and it basically worked out of the box.

So if anyone else encounters this problem: Use 32 bit Python.